# Python multiprocessing: object identifier unique across processes

Tags: python, pickle, python-multiprocessing

Suppose you want to run several processes in parallel (using multiprocessing, possibly on multiple separate machines, as in a cluster), where each process creates a list of new instances of a particular class. Then, you send all these lists back to the parent process, and you want to combine them. Now, can we index these instances by their object id? Can I expect the id's to uniquely identify the objects given that each object was generate on a separate process (possible a separate machine)?

In other words, does the id of an object survive the pickling required to send data between processes, or does the interpreter assign a fresh and unique id to the objects when unpickling them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked, does the id of the object survive the pickling?  The answer is no. The object is pickled and sent to another process, and a new object is created in that process with a new id.  Results are sent back to the original process. The id does not survive… they are different objects.  Id doesn't often survive pickling even in the same process… try `obj2 = pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(object))` and see if `obj2 is object`… it's often not the case.

```
>>> import dill
>>>     
>>> class A(object):
...   pass
... 
>>> b = A()
>>> 
>>> id(b)
4473714832
>>> id(dill.loads(dill.dumps(b)))  
4486366032
>>>
```

However, if you want to maintain an "id" as to understand which object is which, you can.  Just add a `id` attribute that stores some id information (could be a simple number, such as the process "rank" (order), or could be something like a randomly generated hash, or something else… you pick).  If you create this attribute ahead of time, and store the "id" there, it should maintain this information across a `pickle`.  However, if you try to dynamically add an `id` attribute to any object, then `pickle` will "forget" that attribute was added, and the deserialized object will not have the attribute. Alternately, if you use an "advanced" serializer like `dill`, you can pickle a dynamically added attribute on a class instance or almost any object.

Comment: I think you mean that the answer to his question is "yes"- he asked *"Can I expect the id's to uniquely identify the objects given that each object was generate on a separate process (possible a separate machine)?"* He wants to know if the IDs are guaranteed to be unique in the parent process. They are, for the exact reasons you mentioned.

Comment: I mean NO.  I was answering "does the id of the object survive the pickling…"  But I should clarify, thanks.